# Visual Studio 2012 Professional msdev.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have just installed Visual Studio 2012 Professional.  I was hoping to have "msdev.exe" through this but I couldn't find the "msdev.exe".

How do I get / install "msdev.exe" ?

Comment: What is `msdev.exe`?  A quick Google search shows that this question was answered 5 years ago... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/34ce6859-e876-4af9-8d16-0ac5c41df2e4/how-do-i-get-msdevexe

Comment: What are you looking for? The new IDE is named "devenv.exe". Try using the Start Menu.

Answer (score 1):

Try using devenv.exe or just devenv. That is the IDE name from VS 2008.